# V-cloak hides all the content bellow the div it is introduced in

Tags: html, css, vue.js

On my website I have used `v-cloak` with css property `[v-cloak] {display: none}` to hide the content before the vue script is loaded. I want to hide the content only inside the div, however, all the content below the closing tag of the div is also hidden. Is there a way to fix that?

How my code looks:

```html
<!-- Content I want to be displayed -->
<div class="..." v-cloak>
  <!-- Content that I want to be hidden before the vue script is loaded -->
</div>
// Content I want to be displayed
<!-- Content I want to be displayed -->
```

Comment: did you include css - [v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}

Comment: Is it also hidden if you don't use `v-cloak`?

Comment: is your html valid ? (sounds like you didn't close some tag)